# Column Not Found Access Database

Tags: java, swing, ms-access

I am creating an address book application, and I am working on the search function. Whenever I search I get a "Column not found" exception. Here is my code:

```
else if(actionCommand.contentEquals("search"))
        {
        String searchInput = searchBar.getText();
        //String[] searchSplit = searchInput.split("\\s");
        //String searchFirst = searchSplit[0];
        //String searchLast = searchSplit[1];
        personID = null;
        try
        {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:address_book");
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT (personID) FROM names WHERE (lastName) LIKE ('"+searchInput+"')");
            if(resultSet.next())
                personID = resultSet.getString("personID");

            ResultSet firstQuery = statement.executeQuery("SELECT (firstName) FROM names WHERE (personID) LIKE ('"+personID+"')");
            if(firstQuery.next())
                firstNameOutput = firstQuery.getString("firstName");

            ResultSet lastQuery = statement.executeQuery("SELECT (lastName) FROM names WHERE (personID) LIKE ('"+personID+"')");
            if(lastQuery.next())
                lastNameOutput = lastQuery.getString("lastName");

            ResultSet address1Query = statement.executeQuery("SELECT (address1) FROM addresses WHERE (personID) LIKE ('"+personID+"')");
            if(address1Query.next())
                address1Output = address1Query.getString("address1");

            ResultSet address2Query = statement.executeQuery("SELECT (address2) FROM addresses WHERE (personID) LIKE ('"+personID+"')");
            if(address2Query.next())
                address2Output = address2Query.getString("address1");

            ResultSet cityQuery = statement.executeQuery("SELECT (city) FROM addresses WHERE (personID) LIKE ('"+personID+"')");
            if(cityQuery.next())
                cityOutput = cityQuery.getString("city");

            ResultSet stateQuery = statement.executeQuery("SELECT (state) FROM addresses WHERE (personID) LIKE ('"+personID+"')");
            if(stateQuery.next())
                stateOutput = stateQuery.getString("state");

            ResultSet zipcodeQuery = statement.executeQuery("SELECT (zipcode) FROM addresses WHERE (personID) LIKE ('"+personID+"')");
            if(zipcodeQuery.next())
                zipcodeOutput = zipcodeQuery.getString("zipcode");

            ResultSet phoneQuery = statement.executeQuery("SELECT (phoneNumber) FROM phoneNumbers WHERE (personID) LIKE ('"+personID+"')");
            if(phoneQuery.next())
                phoneOutput = phoneQuery.getString("phoneNumber");

            ResultSet emailQuery = statement.executeQuery("SELECT (emailAddress) FROM emailAddresses WHERE (personID) LIKE ('"+personID+"')");
            if(emailQuery.next())
                emailOutput = emailQuery.getString("emailAddress");

            newFunctionWindow();
            personIDBar.setText(personID);
            firstNameBar.setText(firstNameOutput);
            lastNameBar.setText(lastNameOutput);
            address1Bar.setText(address1Output);
            address2Bar.setText(address2Output);
            cityBar.setText(cityOutput);
            stateBar.setText(stateOutput);
            zipcodeBar.setText(zipcodeOutput);
            phoneBar.setText(phoneOutput);
            emailBar.setText(emailOutput);
            statement.close();
            connection.close();
        }

        catch (SQLException sqlException)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sqlException.getMessage(), "Database Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        catch (ClassNotFoundException classNotFound)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, classNotFound.getMessage(), "Driver Not Found", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            System.exit(1);
        }
```

I triple checked all of the column names and there are no typos. I believe all my SQL statements are correct as well, so I am not quite sure what the issue is! Thank you for your help.

Comment: you need to post table structure as well

Comment: First, you have far too many embedded `()` pairs, none of which are necessary. Two, you're using `LIKE` without a wildcard, which means you may as well use `=` instead. Third, you've posted 6 different queries, and not told us which one is causing the error. Fourth, you're concatenating SQL instead of using parameterized queries, leaving yourself wide open to SQL injection. Fifth, you've not included your table structures, so it's pretty much impossible for us to see whether the column actually exists or not in order to answer your question.

Comment: You've committed the classic noob mistake: You've embedded all your database code in a user interface method.  Each of those queries ought to be a separate method in a separate data access class.

Comment: And last but not least, you've not checked the column names carefully enough in **all** your code, not just in the SQL statements. There **is** in fact a simple typo in your code. Looks like copy/paste programming bit you.

Comment: Any reason for all the `selects`, many are accessing the same table and have the same `where`?

Comment: You may also find that the JDBC/ODBC bridge driver is not over supported, better to make use of one of the freely available drivers

Answer (score 2):

```
        ResultSet address1Query = statement.executeQuery("SELECT (address1) FROM addresses WHERE (personID) LIKE ('"+personID+"')");
        if(address1Query.next())
            address1Output = address1Query.getString("address1");

        ResultSet address2Query = statement.executeQuery("SELECT (address2) FROM addresses WHERE (personID) LIKE ('"+personID+"')");
        if(address2Query.next())
            address2Output = address2Query.getString("address1");
```

Whoops - address1 from the address2 field? That won't work. (last line quoted)